# Systemd and encrypted root on debian

Tags: systemd, encryption

I'm on debian 9

I want to boot from an encrypted root,using a usb key

Editing /etc/crypttab...

```
cifr /dev/md0  /dev/disk/by-uuid/88D9-A79B:/FILE luks,keyscript=/lib/cryptsetup/scripts/passdev
```

Reboot..works fine.

Only one problem,systemd stuck with this error,then boot..but I have to wait
1:30 minute!

```
journalctl
```

return this error

```
dev-disk-by\x2duuid-88D9\x2dA79B:-FILE.device: Job dev-disk-by\x2duuid-88D9\x2dA79B:-FILE.device/start failed with result 'timeout'.
```

USB key is formatted with vfat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found.

The command

`/lib/systemd/system-generators/systemd-cryptsetup-generator`

Convert the /etc/crypttab in systemd service.

But it add those bad lines wich cause error

```
After=dev-disk-by\x2duuid-88D9\x2dA79B        
Requires=dev-disk-by\x2duuid-88D9\x2dA79B
```

So the solution is,after boot run

`/lib/systemd/system-generators/systemd-cryptsetup-generator`

This create the service in /tmp

```
/tmp/systemd-cryptsetup@luksmd0.service
```

In my case in luksmd0,in your case can change.
Edit the file,remove the two lines
Then copy it to /etc/systemd/system
And reboot.
At reboot the command

```
systemctl status systemd-cryptsetup@luksmd0.service
```

must return active.